# Define JavaScript variable in cshtml view already been declared

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I define a variable in an IndexJson.cshtml view:

```
@section Scripts{
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var area = "@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["area"].ToString()"
    </script>
```

If I leave the view and then revisit it then I get:

> Identifier 'area' has already been declared

I have a left menu which I make an ajax call and then assign the HTML view in a container like:

```
function MenuClickItem(item) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: item.dataset.area + "/" + item.dataset.controller + "/IndexJson",
        success: function (result) {
            $("#main-container").html(result);
        },
        error: function (res) {
            console.log("Error:" + res)
        }
    });
}
```

Why is this happening? Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Is that error happening in the browser?  That's a client-side error, not server-side.  When you examine the resulting client-side code, is this identifier declared more than once?  Is this code included twice in the resulting page?  Is there other code included in the resulting page which also defines a variable called `area`?

Comment: Could you please tell me how you revisit it ? Use browser's back button?

Comment: @BrandoZhang I am loading the view via ajax call and assign the HTML into a div container. $("#main-container").html(result);

Comment: Ah, then yes. This code will try to create a new `area` variable every time the partial is rendered to the page. This really seems like a long-winded way to retrieve a simple value from the backend where the action should probably return JSON (instead of a partial view) and the value be used directly by JS instead of being rendered to the page's HTML.

Comment: The View is needed , is not just the code that I pasted. it has a lot of HTML code that I did not paste it...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the JavaScript in the partial view is being added and run in the same scope each time and then complains because the variable already exists.

To get around this you should wrap the injected JS in an IIFE so that each partial views JS has it's own scope.

```js
    (function(){
        var area = "@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["area"].ToString()"
    })();
```

This is good practice for most JavaScript code that you will likely write to keep it out of the global scope.

Comment: Unexpected token ']'

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo and should have been a `}` - Fixed

Comment: This is not what i want because I want to use this variable in outer scope. I noticed that if I remove "var" then it works. Is it a correct approach?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't place all your code inside the IIFE.

Answer (score 0):

if i empty my div every time I load the View then it works.

```
function MenuClickItem(item) {
    $("#main-container").html("");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: item.dataset.area + "/" + item.dataset.controller + "/IndexJson",
        success: function (result) {
            $("#main-container").html(result);
        },
        error: function (res) {
            console.log("Error:" + res)
        }
    });
}
```